# a directory explorer middleware for ring clojure

Tags: clojure, ring

Are there any available middleware for ring that would mimic the way a standard file server like apache handles routes

so the handler would look something like this:

```
(wrap-dir "resources/public/")
```

which is very similar to

```
(wrap-file "resources/public/")
```

but will also output directory listings.

Comment: consider asking this to weavejester (the author of ring/compojure)

Comment: I submitted an issue to ring